# Eclipse shows errors in OpenCart code

Tags: eclipse, syntax-error, opencart

I created a project with open cart folders to study it's code and use it as library for developing modules. For some reason it's showing multiple errors all of them in the template files. example:

```
<select name="courier_id" id="courier_id" class="openbayData">
     <option></option>
     <?php foreach($couriers as $courier){ ?>
          <option <?php if(!$order_info['courier_other'] && $order_info['courier_id'] == $courier) echo "selected"; ?>><?php echo $courier; ?></option>
                <?php } ?>
</select>
```

the error is:

```
Multiple annotations found at this line:
 - Processing instruction not closed 
 - Invalid character used in text string (<?php if(!$order_info['courier_other'] && $order_info['courier_id'] == $courier) echo "selected"; ?>>) 
 - Start tag (<option>) not closed properly, expected '>'
```

Also it shows an error in system/database/mysqli.php file

[image]

Any ideas how to fix this?  (I'm using OpenCart 1.5.6)

Comment: What does the IDE say for each error? If there is no error during the application runtime I won't bother with these as IDEs may think there's error where's none... Maybe you have a *logical* error like the `if` is always true thus the `else` part has no sense... Errors in template files may include what the IDE identifies as *invalid* HTML syntax (e.g. not W3C recognized attributes used in JS like `data-*`, etc., or use of inline-styles, etc.). As I said, I wouldn't bother with those and focus rather on developing...

Comment: Also you may have some tool watching the code standards (such as PSR) turned on while the code standard the tool is using may not be the same as of OpenCart (basically they have their own coding standards). Such code-standards-mismatches may also be interpreted by the IDE as *errors* in your code whereas they are not a functional errors...

Comment: the OpenCart installation is working fine. I know they are not actual errors but I'd still like to get rid of them. They may cause importing problems if I want to use OpenCart as a library in a new project.( or is that not the case?)

Comment: I updated the question with the error warning

Comment: *They may cause importing problems if I want to use OpenCart as a library in a new project.* - never heard of such thing. Would be glad if you could point me to the source for this piece of knowledge. As I said, you are going to waste your time - but if you are OK with it, go ahead. I'm definitely not going to waste mine.